# create dialog without id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have a query regarding jquery that i want to create a dialog open and then fill some values in it.
As i have tried to create a dialog using jquery it uses old values because that div already exists on that page.
So i want to create an object of the dialog using jquery and then fill fields in it.
I am using jsmarty and jquery together.
Thanks

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377523/create-dialog-without-id-and-append-in-jquery

Answer (score 5):

You can just do something like this...

```
var jDialogContainer = $(document.createElement("div"));
// add anything to jDialogContainer you want
jDialogContainer.html("hello");
jDialogContainer.dialog({/*options go here*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to create the dialog on the fly then just call dialog on it:

```
$('<div>').html('Hello ' + someVar).dialog()
```

I like to use jQuery template http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/ to create HTML, then call something like dialog on it.