# create dialog without id and append in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, append

I have created a div using jquery that i want to make a dialog.
I want to append another div in that dialog before opening it.
How can i do that??

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377247/create-dialog-without-id-in-jquery

Answer (score 2):

You could add a DOM Object into a div with:

```
$("div#dialog").append("<div></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

create new div and apend old div to it to old div

```
 var newDiv =  $(document.createElement('div')); //Note 1

 $("#ID_OF_OLD_DIV").appendTo($(newDiv));
 $(newDiv).dialog();//or what ever you are using
```

Nte 1: from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery/327068#327068)